# Mac Mini (Late 2014) probelm when running 2 monitors

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

I recently purchased a Mac Mini and had the intention to use it with 2 monitors. I used the HDMI port to plug into one monitor and a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter for the other.

Everything works fine when I have both monitors on.  But when I change one of my monitors to a different input (lets say my XBox) my other monitor runs fine but when I move my mouse around on the screen it lags like crazy.  When I drag my mouse around its response time is terrible and I cant even focus on where my mouse is going.  I've also noticed that when I type something on my keyboard, it takes at least 5 seconds for the letters to show up on the screen.

I've tried different HDMI Cables with no luck.  My only alternative is just to unplug the HDMI cable from the back of my Mac. If someone has a solution I'd really appreciate it! Thanks